# Java Swing - Drag & Drop drawString text

Tags: java, string, swing, drag-and-drop

I've had a look around for this problem but couldn't find an answer...

I currently have a JPanel in which I'm painting a load of unicode characters (music notes) using the `Graphics2D` `g2.drawString()` method.

I have an `ArrayList` of `KeyPress` objects, each of which contains one or more `g2.drawString()` calls.

So each `KeyPress` object is a music note and is painted on the JPanel.

How would I go about adding the functionality to enable the user to select and drag the objects?

Comment: I'm not so sure that this is a true drag & drop problem (one that uses Drag and Drop data transfer support), but I feel that more likely it is a simple MouseListener-click on and drag a screen graphic or sprite type problem. So, what have you tried? Are you familiar with using MouseListeners and MouseMotionListeners?

Comment: I've tried examples with dragging rectangles and other shapes with bounds, but I don't know how to tell if the mouse click is within the area of the String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the tutorial on [supporting user interaction.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/advanced/user.html) It comes down to determining which (if any) objects were underneath the mouse when it was clicked and held. On a drag event, the selected object is moved and the canvas is repainted.

You can obtain the bounds of the string by using `FontMetrics`:

```
String text = "Hello world!";
Rectangle2D bounds = g2.getFontMetrics().getStringBounds(text, g2);
```

I assume the rectangle top-left will be (0, 0), so you need to add (x, y) to it (where x, y are the parameters you passed to drawString).

Comment: Thanks, but how do I get the bounds of the String?

Comment: Thanks for the update, currently I am translating the 'bounds' rectangle, is there a way to set the rectangle's coordinates rather?

Comment: I would just create a new Rectangle2D.Double with x and y set to the coordinates sent to drawString and w and h set to the width and height of the bounds rectangle returned by FontMetrics.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've managed to drag and drop the notes now :) One last question though, how would I drag it so it snaps to certain coordinates?

Comment: Rather than moving the text to exactly where the drag event occurred, move it to the nearest point that you'd like to snap to. Write a function that returns the nearest such point given the drag event location.

Answer (score 3):

Why not put your Strings in JLabels and simply drag them...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class DragLabelEg {
   private static final String[] LABEL_STRINGS = { "Do", "Re", "Me", "Fa",
         "So", "La", "Ti" };
   private static final int HEIGHT = 400;
   private static final int WIDTH = 600;
   private static final Dimension MAIN_PANEL_SIZE = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
   private static final int LBL_WIDTH = 60;
   private static final int LBL_HEIGHT = 40;
   private static final Dimension LABEL_SIZE = new Dimension(LBL_WIDTH,
         LBL_HEIGHT);
   private JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
   private Random random = new Random();

   public DragLabelEg() {
      mainPanel.setPreferredSize(MAIN_PANEL_SIZE);
      mainPanel.setLayout(null);

      MyMouseAdapter myMouseAdapter = new MyMouseAdapter();
      for (int i = 0; i < LABEL_STRINGS.length; i++) {
         JLabel label = new JLabel(LABEL_STRINGS[i], SwingConstants.CENTER);
         label.setSize(LABEL_SIZE);
         label.setOpaque(true);
         label.setLocation(random.nextInt(WIDTH - LBL_WIDTH),
               random.nextInt(HEIGHT - LBL_HEIGHT));
         label.setBackground(new Color(150 + random.nextInt(105), 150 + random
               .nextInt(105), 150 + random.nextInt(105)));
         label.addMouseListener(myMouseAdapter);
         label.addMouseMotionListener(myMouseAdapter);

         mainPanel.add(label);
      }
   }

   public JComponent getMainPanel() {
      return mainPanel;
   }

   private class MyMouseAdapter extends MouseAdapter {
      private Point initLabelLocation = null;
      private Point initMouseLocationOnScreen = null;

      @Override
      public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
         JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();
         // get label's initial location relative to its container
         initLabelLocation = label.getLocation();

         // get Mouse's initial location relative to the screen
         initMouseLocationOnScreen = e.getLocationOnScreen();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
         initLabelLocation = null;
         initMouseLocationOnScreen = null;
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
         // if not dragging a JLabel
         if (initLabelLocation == null || initMouseLocationOnScreen == null) {
            return;
         }
         JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();

         // get mouse's new location relative to the screen
         Point mouseLocation = e.getLocationOnScreen();

         // and see how this differs from the initial location.
         int deltaX = mouseLocation.x - initMouseLocationOnScreen.x;
         int deltaY = mouseLocation.y - initMouseLocationOnScreen.y;

         // change label's position by the same difference, the "delta" vector
         int labelX = initLabelLocation.x + deltaX;
         int labelY = initLabelLocation.y + deltaY;

         label.setLocation(labelX, labelY);
      }
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createGui();
         }
      });
   }

   private static void createGui() {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame("App");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(new DragLabelEg().getMainPanel());
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }
}
```

Comment: i think the author probably want to select a bunch of "labels" then move then all together, in that case, the mouse down, mouse move events need to test whether we have any "selected items" or not

Answer (score 1):

This [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/graphpanel) shows one way to select multiple objects, using keyboard or mouse, and drag
them as a group. It manipulates arbitrary nodes rather than glyphs, but you may find it instructive.